# A textbook for numerical analysis (with solution manual)

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation

This semester I'm studying numerical analysis in university. Our textbook is **Numerical Analysis *by David.R. Kincaid and E. Ward. Cheney***. It is a very good and strong book in numerical analysis with a lot of good exercises but the problem is that it doesn't have any solution manual and I cannot check whether I solved problems true or false. As the main important thing in this course is the ability of solving problem, I'm looking for a good textbook in numerical analysis with strong exercises and also with solution manual.

furthermore, I know that Kincaid's book 6th edition has solution manual but our textbook is its 1991 edition which doesn't have any solution manual and its exercises are completely different with 6th edition. Also the 6th edition of this book as I know doesn't have as many questions as its 1991 edition has, so it is not a good book for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: as you mentioned  Kincaid's book 6th edition has solution manual, can you help me how may I find it?

Comment: @like_math you can find it on amazon website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read "An introduction to Numerical Analysis" by David.F.Mayers. Also another would be "Numerical Methods" by Dahlquist and Bjorck which I think has solutions.