# Exercises/textbooks with solutions for numerical computing?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods

What are some good textbooks with solutions easily available (for example to odd numbered questions) for numerical computing? I currently have Scientific Computing by Michael Heath which has some great exercises but no solutions. Is there a site with exercises and solutions related to topics like Linear Systems of Equations(LU decomposition,Iterative Methods, Overdetermined Systems)?

Comment: Does this work? http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~ridg/newna/nalrs.pdf. You can also try Scahum's Outline of theory and problems of numerical analysis
Book by Francis Scheid as another reference. Lastly, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040405/a-textbook-for-numerical-analysis-with-solution-manual

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This book on numerical linear algebra also has solutions:  http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387341590